# How to clear after calculation JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield, calculator

I wrote a calculator, but the way i concatenate my numbers is so bad because after calculation lets say "5 + 2" when i press equal button it gives "7", the problem comes when i want to do another calculation lets say "6+1" it doesn't do it this way when i press 6 button it gives "76+1" i.e concatenating my result with the new calculation, i tried to fix it but i couldn't without disrupting another functionality. Below is part of the code.

```
private void NineActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    TextField.setText(TextField.getText()+"9");
}                                    

private void OneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    TextField.setText(TextField.getText()+"1");
}                                   

private void TwoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    TextField.setText(TextField.getText()+"2");
}                                   

private void ThreeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    TextField.setText(TextField.getText()+"3");
}                                     

private void FourActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    TextField.setText(TextField.getText()+"4");
}                                    

private void FiveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    TextField.setText(TextField.getText()+"5");
}
```

Comment: not answerable,  without posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) caused a.m. issue

Comment: wait! you are building this using drag and drop. not a good idea for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most simple solution : add clear button and on press clear the text.

The typical solution.:

do something like this:

```
onequalbuttonclick [your equal button action function] 
set equalPress=true;
```

in other functions do  something like this

```
    private void NineActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
if(equalPress){        
textField.setText(9);
equalPress=false;

    }
else
textField.setText((Integer.parseInt(TextField.getText()) + 9));
}
```

Comment on your code:
Instead of these functions just add one actionPerformed event in your class. and then you can use the `getSource()` method to find the button clicked.

Comment: If you have any problem in that code then post your entire code and i'll adjust this in your code.

Comment: I had problem changing it back to false but your method worked, where can i change to false to it knows when its true or false. I couldn't paste my code as an answer because my reputation is less than 10 :)

Comment: If your problem is solved then accept the ans. you will get +5 rep. :)

Comment: OK. So please which part of the code should i put equalPress=false so it resets it?

Comment: @Reimeus must check my bio. Why i joined the sof. :)

Comment: i do the practice for my sake otherwise i forget the syntax's.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just concatenating the `String`, you need to calculate what your result will be, for example:

```
private void NineActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    textField.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(TextField.getText()) + 9));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `TextField.setText("");` at the beginning from every event